# Sum of the geometrico-factorial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

How can I find the sum of the series

$$ 1+1x + 2! \cdot x^2 + 3!\cdot x^3 + \cdots + n! \cdot x^n $$

I was solving this just out of fun but now it doesn't give away. How to form a general formula for such a series? I have been trying my might and even tried wolfram alpha but it answers me in terms of the complex gamma function and exponential integral function (Ei). Is there a simpler formula and if not how can I derive this huge thing?

[MathWorld: Factorial Sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html)

Comment: Letting $x=1$, we get the sequence tabulated at http://oeis.org/A007489 and since there isn't any useful formula given there it's highly unlikely there is one for general $x$.

Comment: Mathematica says that `Sum[k! x^k, {k, 0, n-1}]` is$$(-1/x)e^{-1/x}(E_1(-1/x)-n!x^nE_{n+1}(-1/x))$$

Comment: Should be derivable easily from the [recurrence](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#v)$$nE_{n+1}(z)+zE_n(z)=e^{-z}$$

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not well defined, because it is not clear what exact relation between
the series and "an expression" are you looking for. The series is divergent for
all $x\neq 0$. However:

It is easy to see that $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!x^n$ satisfies the differential
equation
$$x^2y'+(x-1)y+1=0,$$
and the initial condition $y(0)=1$. This is a linear first order differential equation, which can be solved explicitly:
$$y(x)=x^{-1}e^{-1/x}\left(\int_x^\infty t^{-1}e^{1/t}dt+c\right).$$
Unfortunately, $c$ is arbitrary here, but your series is an asymptotic series at $0$
for all these solutions. Or "formal Taylor series", if you wish. So in some sense your series "represents" all these solutions.

For some classes of moderately diverging series the correspondence between
functions and asymptotic series can be made unique. But your series is wildly divergent...

Remark. I recommend the paper by Euler,
"De seriebus divergentibus", first published in Novi Commentarii academiae
scientiarum Petropolitanae 5, 1760, pp. 205-237,
reprinted in Opera Omnia: Series 1, Volume
14, pp. 585 - 617, Eneström-Number E247, English translation is available on
Euler's web page. There he considers (among many other examples)
$$\sum_0^\infty(-1)^nn!x^n$$
but this is slightly less wild than the series you proposed.

Comment: So that's nothing but the integrating factor times the gamma function plus an arbitrary constant (of integration)?? Thanks anyway, it triggered a new method and approach... Having tried all divergent summation methods out there!!!

Comment: @Prateek Kulkarni: This is not  the Gamma function: Gamma does not satisfy ANY algebraic differential equation! Notice that the integrating factor is flat at 0. (All derivatives exist and are equal to zero!). And the integral diverges when $x\to 0$.

Comment: Oh! I see..Thanks! Actually I am in High School, but reading advanced stuff! out of interest (like finished Higher Algebra, Reading Thomas Calculus' and have finished SL Loney trig both parts!) The one you have attached is an alternating series right...I will check it out, in fact it has a appearance in GH Hardy's "Divergent Series"..Thank you very much for your insight!

Comment: @Prateek Kulkarni: I hope you will enjoy reading Euler.

Comment: Sir, by any chance is this you?:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandre_Eremenko

Comment: @Prateek KUlkarni: yes this is me:-) See also www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko for more information, if you are interested.

Comment: Sir I ham honored to interact to you! I am very happy to check your website sir,.....there are cool papers that I am now gonna read sir.. Thanks for answering me sir!

Comment: @Alexandro Eremenko, can you please have a look at my paper here and let me know?       https://vixra.org/abs/2008.0183

Comment: @Prateek Kulkarni: What do you want me to tell you about this paper? The result is certainly not new: the formula $n!=\int_0^\infty b^ne^{-n}db$ is well known, and it remains to sum the finite geometric progression.